# MYSQL How group results from two columns like key/value pairs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I must return all values related to its parent (field_name), in a same column. Currently I have the following query:

```
SELECT dicval.id, dic.field_name, dic.description AS field_description, 
dicval.value,dicval.description FROM adenvie_data_cloud.dictionary_values dicval
INNER JOIN dictionary dic ON dicval.field_name_id = dic.id
ORDER BY dicval.id;
```

And returns as follow:

```
 {
            "id": "1",
            "field_name": "address_type",
            "field_description": "Address Type Indicator",
            "value": "F",
            "description": "Company"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "field_name": "address_type",
            "field_description": "Address Type Indicator",
            "value": "G",
            "description": "General Delivery"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "field_name": "address_type",
            "field_description": "Address Type Indicator",
            "value": "H",
            "description": "Highway"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "field_name": "address_type",
            "field_description": "Address Type Indicator",
            "value": "P",
            "description": "PO Box"
        },
        ...
```

Is it possible group results by field_name, in a SQL statement, in order to return something like this?:

```
{
                "id": "3",
                "name": "addressType",
                "description": "Address Type Indicator",
                "values": {
                    "F": "Company",
                    "G": "General Delivery" ,
                    "H": "Highway",
                    "P": "PO Box",                                    
                    "R": "Rural Route ",
                    "S": "Street"  
                }
```

**PD:**

I've tried `GROUP BY dicval.id, dic.field_name` at ending of SQL Statement without success.

Comment: It'd probably be easier to perform this restructuring on the PHP side.

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(dicval.value, ':', dicval.description) as values` in the query and then use `explode(',', $row['values'])` to turn it into an array in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar this returns all results in one row for the first field_name ```F:Company,G:General Delivery,H:Highway,P:PO Box,R:Rural Route,S:Street,A:Less than $1,B:$1 - $4,999```

Comment: Exactly. That's why you use `explode()` to split it into an array.

Comment: And then you can explode each array element using `:` as the delimiter to get the keys and values.

Comment: You may also like to try the [JSON_OBJECTAGG() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg).

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

The most accurate query in order to get grouped values as key/value pairs was the following:

```
SELECT d.*,
(SELECT CAST(
    CONCAT('[',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                dv2.value ,dv2.description 
            )
        ),
    ']')
  AS JSON) FROM (SELECT * FROM dictionary_values dv WHERE dv.field_name_id = d.id) AS dv2) 
  AS d_value
FROM dictionary d; 
END
```

Finally showing grouped data:

```
{
            "id": "1",
            "field_name": "address_type",
            "description": "Address Type Indicator",
            "category": "base",
            "d_value": "[{\"F\": \"Company\"}, {\"G\": \"General Delivery\"}, {\"H\": \"Highway\"}, {\"P\": \"PO Box\"}, {\"R\": \"Rural Route\"}, {\"S\": \"Street\"}]"
        }
```

Only remains parse d_value string removing \ with str_replace and convert into an array with str_split (PHP)

Comment: Is this a psql solution? If so your question doesn't yet have a psql tag.